# Renderaction refresh / redirect parent page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-partialview, renderaction

I am currently working on an asp.net 4 mvc application and I'm trying to work out the best way to redirect / refresh the parent page after a form is submitted in the child controller.

So in my main view I have

### Main View

```
@Html.RenderAction("child")
```

### Child View / Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create() {    
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        // Save 
        Save();

        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.ToString()); <--- Redirects the main page hack
    }

    return PartialView();    
}
```

What is the correct way to redirect / refresh the main page hosting the renderaction?

DotnetShadow

Comment: Try using RedirectToAction()

Comment: I think I tried something similar and got "Child actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions"

Answer (score 0):

just check how the default Account controller (Internet Application template) has this set for the Login/LogOff actions :

```
    public ActionResult LogOff()
    {
        (...)

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the direction, I did notice that in this case it's a partial view @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial") as opposed to @Html.Renderaction("_LoginPartial") so I think it may not work